os.rename() fails with WinError 3: The system cannot find the path specified on Windows but works on Linux
I am using the following code to semi-automate renaming of media files


def findingmedia(directory):
    media=[]
    for path,subdir, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            #Appends the path and names of video files into media list.
            if file.lower().endswith(video_formats):
                media.append((path,file))
    return media



#Rename according to inputs provided by the user
def rename(media):
    count=0
    for element in media:
        #Take input for the new name from user
        print(f'The name of this file is {element[1]}')
        nname=str(input("Enter the new name for this file \n"))
        splitname=element[1].split('.')
        format=splitname[-1]
        nname=nname+'.'+format
        try:
            file=os.path.join(element[0], element[1])
            newname= os.path.join(element[0], nname)
            #Rename
            os.rename(file, newname)
            print(f'File with name {element[1]} renamed to {nname} successfully')
            count+=1
        except OSError as error:
            print(f"Could not rename file {element[1]} \n Error = {error}")
    return count

this given code works on debian/ubuntu but seems to fail while being run on windows. It outputs the following error code:
Could not rename file mediatest1.mkvError = [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\mg15d\Downloads\The mediatest1 1080p AMZN WEB-DL DDP5 1 H 264-NTb[TGx]\mediatest1.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.H.264-NTb.mkv' -> 'C:\Users\mg15d\Downloads\mediatest1 1080p AMZN WEB-DL DDP5 1 H 264-NTb[TGx]\renamedwuhu.mkv'

While this works perfectly on debian/ubuntu it gives this error on Windows.
I tried looking through solutions on stack and came across using os.renames instead of os.rename, but that outputs the same error code-
 Error = [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\mg15d\\Downloads\\The mediatest1 1080p AMZN WEB-DL DDP5 1 H 264-NTb[TGx]\\mediatest1.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.H.264-NTb.mkv' -> 'C:\\Users\\mg15d\\Downloads\\mediatest1 1080p AMZN WEB-DL DDP5 1 H 264-NTb[TGx]\\renamedwuhu.mkv'


Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names; TLDR Windows is crazy.

@tripleee i dont think thats the issue, i checked the directory name again and it doesn't have any forbidden characters, do you think even square brackets can cause a problem?

it also detects the directory in the first place, shows me the media files, but when it comes to renaming it says cannot find the path specified.

You can't rename the directory and the file at the same time. It works if the destination directory already exists, and effectively moves the file at the same time; but you cannot create a new directory whilst renaming a file.

does directory \mediatest1 1080p AMZN WEB-DL DDP5 1 H 264-NTb[TGx]\ exist, if not then the rename will fail -

@ticktalk it exists, yes. I think the problem was with naming of the folder, because as soon as i changed the folder name to mediatest1, it worked. Still don't understand why the other one wouldn't work.

Windows is weird, changing the directory's name itself and then relaunching the program with the new directory name worked.
